# Size field searchable in Kibana but empty result

Tags: elasticsearch, size, kibana

We have installed the [size plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/mapper-size.html) to find log items in Kibana that have a high impact on our resources.

This results in:

- Being to able to use *_size* in the search bar e.g.: *_size > 1000* (and this works).
- The *_size* field being absent in the available fields list, unless we disable *Hide empty fields*.
- When we disable *Hide empty fields* and add *_size* to the results table, all entries are empty (shown as '-'), but the documents do have a size according to the search query.

How can we make the *_size* field visible in the left menu by default, and show the actual size of the log item in the results table?

Answer (score 0):

At the very bottom of the size plugin [documentation page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/mapper-size-usage.html), you can find this:

> Using _size in Kibana
>
> To use the _size field in Kibana, update the metaFields setting and add _size to the list of meta fields. metaFields can be configured in Kibana from the Advanced Settings page in Management.

So you simply need to go to "Stack Management > Advanced Settings", search for the `metaFields` setting and add `_size` in the input field.

[image]

You can then find the `_size` field in your left menu under the meta fields section:

[image]

Comment: Very plausible, but the field is already present in that advanced setting. Remember: the field is already in the field list, but only when 'hide empty fields' is turned off.

Comment: In my case, I do see the effective size of the document when the _size field is selected. Which version are you running? Are you hitting [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/141225) or [this one](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/121394) by any chance?

Comment: We run 7.17.2, I believe they merged the fix also to this version.